# Reassigning dictionary elements through loop

Tags: c#, loops, dictionary, assign

I have a Dictionary. I've used a loop to add elements in the dictionary and changed them over time through code. How can I revert the elements back to their initial value? 
My code:

```
//for adding to the dictionary
Dictionary<string, string> D = new Dictionary<string, string>();

for(i=0; i<DataSet1.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    row = DataSet1.Tables[0].Rows[i];
    id[i]=row["UserID"].ToString(); 

    D.Add(id[i], "absent");
}   

//for reassigning back to absent
for(int i =0; i<D.Count; i++) D[i.ToString()]="absent";
```

My reassigning loop instead of reassign seems to just add new elements. Initialy counted about 1000 and after the reassign loop it's about 3000.. P.S. Using c# 
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
foreach(var key in d.Keys.ToArray())
{
    d[key] = "absent";
}
```

The `.ToArray()` is needed because the `foreach` loop will throw an error before the second iteration if you try to iterate on `d.Keys` directly.

Comment: You are right it did throw an error. Added the .toArray and it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can enumerate keys of your dictionary and set entries values:

```
foreach(string key in D.Keys.ToArray())
    D[key] = "absent";
```

Also creation of dictionary can be simplified to (with help of Linq to DataSet):

```
var D = DataSet1.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                .ToDictionary(r => r.Field<string>("UserID"),
                              r => "absent");
```

Comment: @usr you are right, keys should be enumerated instead, thanks

Comment: Oh jeez.. I was so paniked that I completely forgot about foreach. THANK YOU. you are a life saver!

Comment: I get an error saying Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Comment: @Vantalk as, JLRishe suggested you should dump keys to array or list for enumeration